# Wordpress Not Updating Stylesheet

Tags: wordpress, stylesheet

My wordpress website is not updating the stylesheet its using instead of style.css it is showing "style.css?ver=3.8.3"

I want to know why is this happening and where does this version thingie come from since I've checked both via admin panel and the ftp and have reset cache but still its getting its styles from some other version of the styelsheet.

It would be really helpful if someone points out the logic behing this. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the '$ver' parameter to 'null' in the call to style-sheet in your theme files

```
wp_enqueue_style( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $media );
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to the **functions.php** file of your WordPress theme

```
function remove_cssjs_query_string( $src ) {
 if( strpos( $src, '?ver=' ) )
 $src = remove_query_arg( 'ver', $src );
 return $src;
}
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', 'remove_cssjs_query_string', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'script_loader_src', 'remove_cssjs_query_string', 10, 2 );
```

This code will remove query strings (**?ver=**) parameter from all the CSS and JS files on your site.

```
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', 'remove_cssjs_query_string', 10, 2 );
```

Above line removes query strings from all CSS files

```
add_filter( 'script_loader_src', 'remove_cssjs_query_string', 10, 2 );
```

Above line removes query strings from all JS files

Hope it helps :)

Source : http://belnad.com/remove-ver-query-string-wordpress-css-js-files/